# Relationship between subharmonic functions and gradient flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Question.
Let's say that $F(x,y)$ is a function with $$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} \ge 0$$ everywhere (such a function is called subharmonic). What effect does the gradient flow of $F(x,y)$
have on area?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know of any ways to relate the change in area with quantities related to a vector field? (Hint: it involves a divergence)